# Paypal Skipping Order step

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal

I am using PayPal Express Checkout, i set "Skip Order Review Step" to "No" but its still redirecting user to PayPal Page after selecting PayPal as a payment Method and Skipping order Review step. it should redirect after complete 5th (Order Review) step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an external payment method, the workflow is the following :

- The user is redirected to the payment page of this method directly after step 4.
- The user confirm his payment on the external website.
- The user is redirected to Magento website.

And it is the same for each external payment method. Having the 5th step with an external payment method is not the usual way.
The "Skip Order Review Step" option of Paypal Express Checkout is about the landing page you are redirected after paying on Paypal website. If you put it to "No", the review step **after** Paypal process will be skipped.

Comment: Thanks for Answer.. i think its better if page redirect after 5th step (Order Review) so user can check cart items.. after payment what is the use of order review? Can i do it like this?

Comment: I'd like to know as well how can we avoid this new "flow". It's bizarre that people can only check their order after they pay, and not before, like traditionally you do. It makes no sense to remove this step...

Comment: @Peanuts they can still check their order prior to placing it, no?